# Vue login form - The "login" attribute is required

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a basic Vue login form which sends 2 fields through to a post request. I'm getting an error saying 'The "login" attribute is required', I can't figure out what's wrong with the code?

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>Sign in</h3>
        <div class="row" v-if="errorMessage">
            <div class="alert alert-danger"><p>{{ errorMessage }}</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" v-if="successMessage">
            <div class="alert alert-success"><p>{{ successMessage }}</p></div>
        </div>
        <form @submit.prevent="OnLogin">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userSigninLogin">Email</label>
                <input name="login" type="text"
                class="form-control" id="userSigninLogin"
                placeholder="Enter your email" v-model="apiRequest.login">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userSigninPassword">Password</label>
                <input name="password" type="password"
                class="form-control" id="userSigninPassword"
                placeholder="Enter your password" v-model="apiRequest.password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      apiRequest: new this.$request({
        login: '',
        password: '',
      }),
      errorMessage: '',
      successMessage: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    OnLogin() {
      this.apiRequest.addStore(this.$store);
      this.apiRequest.post('login')
        .then((response) => {
          this.successMessage = response;
          this.errorMessage = '';
        })
        .catch((errors) => {
          this.errorMessage = errors;
          this.successMessage = '';
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post your error message? and the stack trace if you have it.

Comment: I just had another look, at first I thought the message being displayed on the screen (The "login" attribute is required) was the error message, but it's actually being read as the success message. I'll need to go back and dig more before I add more information